# Eclipse AWS Explorer can't see Dyanmodb tables created with Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to use AWS Explorer in Eclipse but it doesn't show newly created tables. When I use [this Java sample code](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/gettingstartedguide/GettingStarted.Java.01.html) to create a table AWS Explorer doesn't show the new table after refreshing. It doesn't show it in either the local or us-west-2 region. If I run the code again it throws an Exception saying "Cannot create preexisting table ..." so the Movies table was created. If I change the second parameter in

`new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("http://localhost:8000", "us-west-2")`

by deleting the '2' I can run again successfully. Running a second time gives the same error.

What does the second parameter to EndpointConfiguration() do? It doesn't have to be a valid region name. Is this supposed to correspond to one of the regions in the AWS Explorer region drop list? Why do I need a region if I'm running locally? The second parameter does something since changing it allows me to create another table, but having it be a region name just muddies the waters. Apparently it can be anything. The JavaDoc is no help on this.

The Java code apparently is creating the Movie table somewhere else than AWS Explorer is looking.  I've also tried RazorSql and it doesn't see the Movie table either.  Both see tables created with AWS Explorer though.

Where does the Java code create its tables?

Comment: Did you find an answer for this? I have the same issue in Visual Studio.  The tables definitely exist but AWS does not display them.  +1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the client line:
new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("http://localhost:8000", "local")

I figured it out by checking what .db files were being created for the version of DynamoDB that I'm using. I saw one with "us-west-2" and another with "local". I decided to give "local" a try as the region and it worked! I can now see tables that were created using the "local" region.

I've posted a comment on the Amazon DynamoDB Developer guide explaining the need for an update to their code examples.